# Access a cluster via SSH in a Java macro

Tags: java, fluid-dynamics

I have a Star-CCM (CFD software) java macro that tells the CFD simulation to run on my local machine,through the line:

`simulation_0.getSimulationIterator().runAutomation();`

I want to tell Star-CCM to run the simulation on a cluster (usually I use PuTTY for this, but this have to be automatic), via SSH. What should I change in this line?

Best regards,
Carlos

I did not try anything yet, I'm a newbie in Java, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. I've never seen macros in Java. Also note that Java is not JavaScript, so decide which you use and remove the extra tag. A [mcve] would be helpful, including what command you currently run t achieve this. See also [ask].

Comment: I assume you're talking about [this kind of Java macros](https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/topic/0TO4O000000YThBWAW/simcenter-starccm-java-macros) so I've adjusted the tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to tell Star-CCM to run the simulation on a cluster (usually I use PuTTY for this, but this have to be automatic), via SSH. What should I change in this line?

You can try to follow this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.cdadapco.star.RemoteMachine;
import com.cdadapco.star.Simulation;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String remoteMachineHostname = ...;

        RemoteMachine remoteMachine = new RemoteMachine(remoteMachineHostname);

        Simulation simulation = Simulation.getActiveSimulation();

        simulation.getSimulationIterator().runAutomation(remoteMachine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm not sure if I would just substitute the referred line for that code. Can I send my whole java macro here? It's on line 74 and, for what I understand, already inside a Main.